# HTML anchor href using # hash to an id on another page when id present on first page

Tags: html

I'm struggling to get anchor tags with # fragments in to navigate to a new page when the id is found in the current page.

**PAGE 1 on url /page1**

I have HTML:

```
<a href="/page2#bananas">go to bananas on page 2</a>
<div id="bananas">bananas on page 1</div>
```

**PAGE 2 on url /page2**

I have HTML:

```
<div id="bananas">bananas on page 2</div>
```

When one clicks the link, the browser just scrolls to the `<div>` with `id="bananas"` on page 1 and doesn't go to page 2. How can make it go to page 2 instead?

If I right click and choose open in new tab it works fine and goes to /page2#bananas as I want. Interestingly, `target="_blank"` doesn't work on left mouse click, and it doesn't even open a new tab in Chrome!

Answer (score 0):

Div ID is correct.

For the anchor add the `.html` extension:

```
<a href="page2.html#bananas">go to bananas on page 2</a>
```

Comment: hmm... I don't think that solves the trick for me. I've tried with and without the first / and with and without the .html... but the behaviour doesn't change.  (did you deliberately omit the / before page2 in your href?

Comment: @user8255871 Yes I deliberately removed the backslash. .HTML, hash and ID.

Comment: hmmm. it's still not working for me. maybe I'm being an idiot... I'll see if I can dynamically rename the id's based on my templates.